# Integers and Diophantine Equations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

Assume that $n,m,p\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\gcd(nm,p)=1$. Show that $\gcd(m,p)=1$. 
For this question I don't think the $n$ factor effects the $\gcd$, but I don't know how to prove this mathematically (proofs are hard for me).

Comment: Try to understand it intuitively. It isn't hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$gcd(mn,p)=1$ so there exists integers $u$ and $v$ such that $umn+pv=1$, hence $(un)m+pv=1$, hence since $gcd(m,p)$ divides $(un)m+pv=1$, then it is $1$.

Comment: Im still confused about what you meant when you wrote "since gcd(m,p) divides (un)m+pv=1, then it is 1", would you mind explaining that part?

Comment: $gcd(m,n)$ divides any linear combination of $m$ and $n$, and hence divides $1$, since $1=(un)m+pv$

Comment: Can you give an argument why $1=(un)m + pv$? It seems you use Bézout's identity, but maybe I oversee something.

Answer (score 0):

$\gcd(mn,p) = 1$ means the system
$$
mn = q_1 d \quad p = q_2 d
$$
has only the solution $d = 1$ for integer $q_1$, $q_2$.
If $\gcd(m,p) = d' > 1$ it would solve
$$
m = q_1' d' \quad p = q_2' d'
$$
which would solve
$$
mn = (q_1' n) d'
$$
as well, which would mean $d'$ would be a common divisor of $mn$ and $p$ as well. But we already know that there is only $1$ as common divisor. 
So our assumption $d'>1$ must be wrong and we are left with $1=d'=\gcd(m,p)$.